# Process exited with status one State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: javascript, java, heroku

Did the app on video uploaded to Heroka but something went wrong. I think the problem is here somewhere:

[image: error message reuploaded from external service to SO]

I can't publish the code, why?

> ````
> 2020-06-17T22:11:32.980579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-headland-54183.herokuapp.com request_id=82b53c0f-f89a-4674-bcab-494f4f7644eb fwd="46.101.40.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=httpsenter >```
> ````

This leads to this error:

> ```sh
> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail
> ```

If there is something wrong with the question, please let us know what it is, because the previous one was just deleted, I wrote to support, but they did not respond.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know why your previous question was deleted, but since you ask I'll try to explain what was wrong with this post. You [should not post images of code or of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). If you are trying to upload using Java/JS it's imperative your include the source code in the question. Otherwise, questions that are not about programming are not allowed on this site. Please consider the guidelines: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks. for the answer. It is written above that when trying to publish the code, an error occurs, why. Because of it, I had to publish a screenshot of the code instead of publishing the code, what difference does it make, the code or the screenshot? What's wrong with my code? Is it hard to see in the screenshot?

Comment: There was probably some sort of error when copying the code. Click the "edit" link on the left below the question and try to copy-past the code without formatting. If it works ping me here by writing a comment and I'll format it.

Comment: too long by 5934 characters
 Can I somehow attach a text document?

Comment: You should consider how to create a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You could use https://pastebin.com but there's something wrong if you so much code is needed.

Comment: You can see my code on the screenshot